# How do I improve the performance of this Excel to PDF converter I wrote?

Tags: c#, performance, pdf, datagridview, excel-interop

---

### Selected View Row Data -> Excel -> PDF

**Tools:** Excel com interop

Here's the gist of what my program does,

1. It reads data from a MASSIVE database of 90,000 rows, or around that estimate. (Only those selected rows from a datagridview, though the goal is to convert wholesale)
2. Assigns them to variables, variables are written into a pre-formatted excel file's cells (for its cell arrangement, font sizes, color etc, unavoidable).
3. And lastly I convert the excel file into a PDF, my main objective.

Unfortunately, my program takes about an hour to process 700 items only, though i'm not sure if it's my machine, an i3, 2GB ram notebook unit.
The code below only converts selected records from a datagridview, which i used as a temporary stop-gap measure to test large sets of data.

My question is, how do I improve its performance? The code I wrote is already relatively simple and it works, I don't know where to look to see what's slowing it down and how to improve the write speed.
These are the suspects of the performance hits:

1. The data is read from a datagridview, though the view is backed by an Access database, there should be no performance hit from reading the datagridview alone.
2. Writing to Excel could take some time, I cut off a block of code to shorten my code entry for StackOverflow. The cell write may use some resources.
3. Excel to pdf is essentially 1 line of code, so I'm not sure if there's a hit, or if any improvement is at all possible here.
4. Perhaps there is a hit when looping through the datagridview to the current index of the for loop in the code block below.
5. My resource monitor seems to detect several signatures of EXCEL.exe being processed and terminated, this should be normal as per the code however, since none of them linger longer than they should.

Assistance in the matter is greatly appreciated!

---

```
if (DGVmain.RowCount > 0)
{
    if (DGVmain.SelectedCells.Count <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    //Source
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx";
    openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    lblSuccess.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
    lblPathings = Path.ChangeExtension(openFileDialog.FileName, null);
    int count = DGVmain.SelectedRows.Count;
    int ballast = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow selectedRow in DGVmain.SelectedRows)
    {
        //Drag
        if (lblSuccess.Text == null)
            return;
        //Drag
        if (lblSuccess.Text == null)
            return;
        string drags = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[0].Value);
        string dragsy = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[1].Value);
        string drag = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[2].Value);
        string drag2 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[3].Value);
        string drag3 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[4].Value);
        string drag4 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[5].Value);
        string drag5 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[6].Value);
        string drag6 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[7].Value);
        string drag7 = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[8].Value);
        \\trimmed this part down for Stackoverflow
        Persona = drag;
        generateID();
        //Initialize the Excel File
        try
        {
            ballast++;
            lblItem.Text = "Item #" + ballast;
            Xls = new Excel.Application();
            WBs = Xls.Workbooks;
            WB = WBs.Open(lblSuccess.Text, 0, false, 5, "", "", true,
                XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            if (WB == null)
            {
                Xls.Quit();
                Xls = null;
                WB = null;
                return;
            }
            SS = WB.Worksheets;
            WS = SS.get_Item(1);
            //Tin Algorithm
            string input = drag23;
            string digit1 = "0";
            string digit2 = "0";
            string digit3 = "0";
            string digit4 = "0";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder partBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int partsSplitted = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= input.Length; i++)
            {
                partBuilder.Append(input[i - 1]);
                if (i % 3 == 0 && partsSplitted <= 3)
                {
                    sb.Append(' ');
                    sb.Append(partBuilder.ToString());
                    partBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    partsSplitted++;
                }
            }
            sb.Append(partBuilder.ToString());
            string formatted = sb.ToString().TrimStart();
            string[] formatCollection = formatted.Split(' ');
            digit1 = formatCollection[0];
            digit2 = formatCollection[1];
            digit3 = formatCollection[2];
            digit4 = formatCollection[3];
            //Names
            WS.Cells[14, 2] = dragsy + ",  " + drag + drag2;
            // Write to cells here
            WS.Cells[8, 8] = "2016";
            WS.Cells[8, 29] = drag24;
            WS.Cells[8, 34] = drag25;
            WS.Cells[11, 9] = digit1;
            WS.Cells[11, 12] = digit2;

            //Trimmed for StackOverflow!

            WB.Save();
            try
            {
                WB.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, finalformat);

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error occurred: " + ex, "General error exception");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Write Excel: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            WB.Close();
            Xls.Quit();
            releaseObject(SS);
            releaseObject(WS);
            releaseObject(WBs);
            releaseObject(WB);
            releaseObject(Xls);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the time signatures, I have no idea what these loaded modules are or what they do. Don't remember including them/noticing them before either.

New thread link:

[How do I write this Excel Interop syntax in EPPLUS syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154441/how-do-i-write-this-excel-interop-syntax-in-epplus-syntax)

Comment: Did you measure what takes so long? That might help you debug where the performance is bad, because it doesn't sound like something that should take that long.

Comment: 90k record is not massive. Depending on what's in a record it may even the considered small. Moving data to Excel is most likely the culprit. Not sure if there is a way to bulk insert the data.. So do put in a few looging calls to test which part takes up which time..

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that yet, with sleep and timers? I'll try to look up the subject, but let me know if you have an idea on what I should be using. @TaW For the sake of clarity, the Excel file is 31 Columns, each column  consists of number type data. The best I know to test performance is my task manager, which states that it isn't even using all of my CPU power, HDD usage spikes to 100% though.

Comment: _I'm not sure how to do that yet, with sleep and timers? _ Um, no, on the contrary: simply add a Console.Writeline(" strating to ..." + DateTime.Now) calls to see how the time is consumed.

Comment: Ah, such a simple suggestion I did not think of it. I'll respond with the details when I get back on my work machine.

Comment: @TaW, Updated with the time signatures, it took roughly 3 mins to convert 3 records into pdf's.

Comment: Hm, hard to tell. Btw: As a general rule you never touch the GC; any reason you do it here? Also. Do you go over a network? How (beyond the DBMS)?

Comment: @TaW, I read about it in StackOverflow threads regarding possible edge cases when you try closing an excel file you mess with. However, those threads were pretty old so I'm not sure if this method is deprecated. The guy who suggested it seemed to know what he was doing. So far, I improved the speed abit by choosing to not save the excel file at all, since saving it was unnecessary. Now it writes 1 row is to 1 pdf every 5 seconds. Good, but when there are 90,000 records, I'll need to optimize it more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that from the first save to the final PDF creation takes about 60 seconds.  If you're going to save and export 4 times, that seems like a reasonable time span.  If your performance concern is with the ~80 seconds from the start of the foreach loop to the first save, I'd guess your problem is with these lines:

```
WS.Cells[14, 2] = dragsy + ",  " + drag + drag2;
// Write to cells here
WS.Cells[8, 8] = "2016";
WS.Cells[8, 29] = drag24;
WS.Cells[8, 34] = drag25;
WS.Cells[11, 9] = digit1;
WS.Cells[11, 12] = digit2;

//Trimmed for StackOverflow!
```

As mentioned by [TaW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3152130/taw):

> Moving data to Excel is most likely the culprit. Not sure if there is a way to bulk insert the data.

Well, **there is a way to bulk insert**, but you're code wins the *"Most Unmanageable Code of the Year"* award.  So, I'm not sure how you're going to implement it, but you'll want to make use of `Range` and `Value` instead of `Cell`. In your case it would probably look something like...

```
string[,] values = new string[15, 35];  //or objects
values[7, 7] = "2016";
values[7, 28] = drag24;
values[7, 33] = drag25;
values[10, 8] = digit1;
values[10, 11] = digit2;
// etc.

Range range = WS.Range[WS.Cells[1, 1], WS.Cells[15, 35]];
range.Value = values;
```

You could also use `object` instead of `string` if you want to use numbers.  You could also replace `Value` with `Text` if you're really only using strings.

Comment: While we're on the subject of optimizing code, I was wondering if you had any idea how I can improve the " string drags = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[0].Value); " code block I have above. It's redundant and messy. I've already marked this the answer.

Comment: Oh, and I punched your code in, but now it seems to replace the entire excel file with one cell. I migrated to use EPPLUS for its performance enhancements over interop and now I go 3-2 seconds is to 1 row made into a PDF. The only thing taking long now is the PDF conversion, that still uses interop. Still, I want to get the optimized code you wrote to work. In EPPLUS, I cannot write `Range range = WS.Range[WS.Cells[1, 1], WS.Cells[15, 35]];` and instead wrote `ExcelRange range = WS.Cells["A1: AH106"];` Which is definitely wrong and the cause for the whole sheet replacement. Any suggestions?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/q/31433189/1474994 , WS.Cells["7:9"] works, so I can't imagine yours doesn't. I'm not as familiar with eeplus (though I've been meaning to), but maybe take out the space after the :