# How do I write this Excel Interop syntax in EPPLUS syntax

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, epplus

Someone suggested to me a method to improve my code by making it more manageable through the use of objects:

```
string[,] values = new string[15, 35];  //or objects
values[7, 7] = "2016";
values[7, 28] = drag24;
values[7, 33] = drag25;
values[10, 8] = digit1;
values[10, 11] = digit2;
// etc.

Range range = WS.Range[WS.Cells[1, 1], WS.Cells[15, 35]];
range.Value = values;
```

His suggestion, but since I moved from interop to EPPLUS, the following syntax no longer works.

```
Range range = WS.Range[WS.Cells[1, 1], WS.Cells[15, 35]];
```

What would a working form of this look like in EPPLUS Syntax?

Replacing it with this didnt work out right and replaced everything in the sheet:

```
ExcelRange range = WS.Cells["A1: AH106"]
```

Perhaps something like this?

```
= sheet.Cells["A1:,12:12,14:14"]
```

Comment: Using a 2D string array will make things more difficult if you want to use the EPPlul `LoadFrom*` methods.  Better off with some kind of collection of collections.  But if you have to keep your current structure simply loop through them yourself which will be more efficient anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you mean, but here's a simple example with a custom object, and arrays:

Test object:

```
class TestObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Populating a sheet with the custom object, and arrays:

```
IEnumerable<TestObject> objectList = new List<TestObject>()
{
    { new TestObject() {Id = 0, Name = "zero" } },
    { new TestObject() {Id = 1, Name = "one" } }
};
var values = new List<object[]>()
{ 
    new string[] { "one", "two" }, 
    new string[] { "three", "four" }
};

using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    // note second parameter gives you headings
    sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection<TestObject>(objectList, true);
    sheet.Cells["A4"].LoadFromArrays(values);
    File.WriteAllBytes(OUTPUT, package.GetAsByteArray());
}
```

Comment: I did read about this, and it does seem like what I want, but I wasn't familliar with the IEnumerable function outside of Linq. It's pretty clear what it does though the way you wrote it, I'll give it a shot and see what happens.